# Styling two images within a div, differently

Tags: html, css

Wanting to style two images within a div and give them different CSS styling.

```
<div id="l1">
 <h4>Thorlax Comfort Socks </h4>
 <img src="images/comfortSocks.png">
 <p> These socks offer you the best in comfort. 
 <h3> $9.99 </h3>
 <img src="images/CheckItOut.png">
</div>
```

How might I go about giving the two images different styling attributes. Below is how I would usually go about it. How do I target just the bottom image, the "images/CheckItOut.png"

```
l1 img { etc etc etc
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a feeling this is a simple question but I haven't encountered the problem before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give each image a class and style each class. For example:

```
<img src="images/comfortSocks.png" class="socks">
<img src="images/CheckItOut.png" class="checkitout">
```

then your CSS

```
img.socks {
    ....
}
img.checkitout {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give different ids to your img.

```
<div id="l1">
 <h4>Thorlax Comfort Socks </h4>
 <img id="img1" src="images/comfortSocks.png">
 <p> These socks offer you the best in comfort. 
 <h3> $9.99 </h3>
 <img id="img2" src="images/CheckItOut.png">
</div>
```

Css

```
#img1{


}

#img2{

}
```

Comment: It's better to use `class` rather than `id`, classes can be reused and have you less chance of running into specificity issues. Same principal though.

Answer (score 1):

Adding classes to your div's is the best option. However, if you can't. You can use the "of-type" pseudo thingies:

Examples

Selects the first image

```
#l1 img:first-of-type {
    // code here
}

#l1 img:nth-of-type(1) {
    // code here
}
```

Selects the 2nd and last image

```
#l1 img:last-of-type {
    // code here
}

#l1 img:nth-of-type(2) {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution would be to use the css nth-child() selector.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

This is useful if you are styling your first and second images the same every time.

In your case it would be:

```
 #l1 img:nth-child(2){
   css for first image
 }
 #li img:nth-child(5){
   css for second image
 }
```

Comment: nth-child won't work. As with nth-child(1) & nth-child(2) it will select the h4 and the first img. And as the first child is not an image. The first piece of code won't work at all. You should use nth-child(2) and nth-child(5) in this case. Better is to use nth-of-type ;)

Comment: Good point.  Added edit to clarify the use of nth-child() in this case.  nth-of-type is the best route in this case